# How can I see what case/report/user data a CommCare user has access to on mobile?

Tags: commcare

When you sync CommCare on mobile, what data is included in that restore file?  Is this data dependent on what user I'm logged in as?  On what app I'm using?  On what build of that app the user has deployed?  How can I view this file (assuming I know the username, app, and build being used)?

Answer (score 1):

The restore payload includes:

- ID of the sync
- User registration data
- Fixtures

  - Groups
  - Lookup tables (can be user dependent)
  - Products
  - Programs
  - Mobile reports (application / application build dependent)
  - Organizations (user dependent)
- Cases

You can view the data at the following URL:

```
 https://www.commcarehq.org/a/{my-project}/phone/admin_restore
```

Also see the docs here: https://help.commcarehq.org/display/commcarepublic/CommCare+Sync+Data

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the new "Evaluate Xpath" in the App Preview screen to explore what's in the restore file now.  It's covered here:

https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Web+Apps+Data+Preview

This video covers it a bit also:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqhAcOijOr8&feature=youtu.be&t=7m10s

Comment: I'm actually not sure that's correct, as I think that App Preview and/or Web Apps actually doesn't sync the App-Specific restore file.  We've seen differences in which reports data is available to the same user on App Preview vs. mobile because App Preview will sync all data the user could need for any mobile report in the domain, not just in the app.